# Xbuild .csproj | References could not be found

Tags: c#

I'm actually working on a project using VS 2015.

Recently, I rented a server where I would like to switch my project but I had some issues.

When I try to build my .csproj with xbuild, I meet errors during the compilation.

Compilation line:

```
sudo xbuild projetML.csproj
```

Errors:

```
Connection/ConnectionDB.cs(44,22): error CS1684: Reference to type
`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<TResult>' claims it is defined assembly
`mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089', but it could not be found
```

It seems that the dll "System.Threading.Tasks.Task" could not be found but when I work on VS, there is no problem with that.

The line in Connection/ConnectionDB.cs is a connection line to a mongo databa using MongoDB driver:

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient client = new MongoClient(host):
MongoDB.Driver.IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase(db);

database.RunCommandAsync((Command<BsonDocument>)"{ping:1}")
.wait();
```

After some search, it seems that .RuncommandAsync can return something of type "System.Threading.Tasks.Task" but on VS, it doesn't care of this type.

Thanks for your help.

Note: I have the same issue with "System.Threading.CancellationToken".

Comment: What is the output of `mono --version`?

Comment: Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
 TLS:           __thread
 SIGSEGV:       altstack
 Notifications: epoll
 Architecture:  amd64
 Disabled:      none
 Misc:          softdebug 
 LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
 GC:            sgen

Comment: Please say goodbye to such ancient versions. Mono 5.0 is coming, and at least you should use 4.x from http://mono-project.com